# pandas groupby() receiving error message "level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex"

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to perform a simple groupby operation but it's receiving an error message "level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex" and being a python newbie, I don't understand what that means or know where the error is.

In my data frame di, I have three variables disabled, wpfinwgt, and rhcalmn, whose values run from 1 to 12 (one for each calender month). I want to sum the two variables by rhcalmn. the code I have is:

```
di_bymonth=di.groupby(level=['rhcalmn']).sum()[['disabled','wpfinwgt']]
```

and I get

```
ValueError: level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex
```

What is wrong with it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think just `di.groupby('rhcalmn').sum()` will work fine

Comment: The `level` param is only valid when you have a multi-index which it looks like your df does not have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you need `level` parameter. why cant you just use

```
> di_bymonth=di.groupby('rhcalmn').sum()[['disabled','wpfinwgt']]
```

Add some sample data, If this is not what you are expecting

Comment: Thanks! this works. I don't know why I put level there.